# Adding a line of text with a colored cell based the latest observations

Tags: php, xml, html, xml-parsing

Need help taking the following code and add a line after the `MSG_TXT` foreach section that says something like:

```
Recreational Activity - Safe or Caution or Dangerous
```

Depending on the most recent discharge levels from the observed discharged data.

- 45-499 Safe in Green a green block with white font
- 500-799 Caution in a yellow block with white font
- and anything over 800 Dangerous in Bright Red with white font.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/NOD_R.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>

<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[0]->ROW as $MSG) :?>
<?php echo '<h4>', $MSG->MSG_TXT; '</h4>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
&nbsp;

<!-- Table Style -->
<style>
table {border: 2px solid #fff;}
table td {height: 15px;}
table td {border: 1px solid #fff; }
table tr {border: 1px solid #fff; }
table td {padding: 3px; }
</style>

<h2>Observed Data</h2>
<table>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Day</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Time(EST)</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Reservoir Elev.(behind    dam)*</span</td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Tailwater Elev.(below dam)*</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Avg Hourly Discharge*  </span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW as $obs) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_DAY; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_HR; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->UPSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->DOWNSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<h2>Predicted Data</h2>
<table>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><span style="margin:25px; font-weight:bold">Day</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Average Inflow* </span</td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Midnight Elevation*</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Average Outflow*</span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[2]->ROW as $pred) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $pred->PREDICTED_DAY; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->DAILY_AVG_INFLOW; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->MIDNIGHT_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->DAILY_AVG_OUTFLOW; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

Update:

Thanks to the comments below I was able to add this to the code and get everything but the output being Safe, Caution, or Dangerous.  It's outputting the flow rate number.  How can I get that switched?

```
 <?php
$discharge = (int) $xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[46]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;
$discharge_range = [
    'safe'      => [ 'min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 499 ], 
    'caution'   => [ 'min_range' => 500, 'max_range' => 799 ], 
    'dangerous' => [ 'max_range' => 800 ]
];
$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};
echo "Recreational Activity - ";
echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">'.$discharge.'</span>';
?>
```

Comment: See my edit below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres one way you could do it, there are many ways to check a value is between a range.

**Define your CSS**

```
<style>
    .discharge-safe {
        background: green;
        color: white;
    }

    .discharge-caution {
        background: yellow;
        color: white;
    }

    .discharge-dangerous {
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Get the value from your XML which you want to check, then use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with a min and a max to check the values and assign a var which will be used to select the CSS class.

```
<?php
$discharge = (int) $xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[0]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;

$discharge_range = [
    'safe'      => [ 'min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 499 ], 
    'caution'   => [ 'min_range' => 500, 'max_range' => 799 ], 
    'dangerous' => [ 'max_range' => 800 ]
];

$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};

echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">'.$discharge.'</span>';
?>
```

https://3v4l.org/0RRXY

You could also use just a bog standard if else with a comparison on the value, but where the fun in that:

```
if ($discharge > 0 && $discharge <= 499) {
   $discharge_class = 'safe';
} elseif ($discharge >= 500 && $discharge <= 799) {
    $discharge_class = 'caution';
} elseif ($discharge >= 800) {
    $discharge_class = 'dangerous';
}
```

---

**Edit:**

> This works kinda. It's outputting the discharge number in the colored
>   box and not "Recreational Activity - safe, caution, or dangerous".

Then change the output to not show the number but the class value:

```
echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">Recreational Activity - '.$discharge_class($discharge).'</span>';
```

> It's also not using the latest observation, if you look at the xml,
>   there is like 48 hours of obs. I'm wanting only the latest obs to be
>   used.

Then get the last element in the array, which is the latest from what I can see.

```
// last item
$discharge = $xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[count($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW)-1]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;
```

Try this:

```
<style>
    .discharge-safe {
        background: green;
        color: white;
    }

    .discharge-caution {
        background: yellow;
        color: white;
    }

    .discharge-dangerous {
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<?php
$url = "http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/NOD_R.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// last item
$discharge = $xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[count($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW)-1]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;

$discharge_range = [
    'safe'      => [ 'min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 499 ], 
    'caution'   => [ 'min_range' => 500, 'max_range' => 799 ], 
    'dangerous' => [ 'max_range' => 800 ]
];

$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};

echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">Recreational Activity - '.$discharge_class($discharge).'</span>';
?>
```

Comment: This works kinda.  It's outputting the discharge number in the colored box and not "Recreational Activity - safe, caution, or dangerous".  It's also not using the latest observation, if you look at the xml, there is like 48 hours of obs.  I'm wanting only the latest obs to be used.  Each hour the xml is updated with the latest obs for that hour.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the snark!